# recursive definition of a PROPOSITION

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(define( app list1 list2)
  (if(empty? list1) list2
     (cons (car list1) (app(cdr list1)list2))))

(app ((list "↔" "→" "∧" "⊕" "∨" "¬")) (list "P" "Q" "R" "S" "U" "X" "Y" "Z"))




(define L (list "↔" "→" "∧" "⊕" "∨" "¬"))
(define ( f L n)
  (if (= n 0) "p"
      (string-append "p" (car L) (f(cdr L) (- n 1)))))

(f L 3)
```

You have the following recursive definition of a PROPOSITION:

1. T,  F   are propositions         ( truth value of propositional variables)
2. List item
3. Propositional letters P, Q , R, S,  U, X, Y, Z  are propositions.
4. If  A is a proposition  the ¬A is a proposition.
5. If A and B are propositions    then
   A⊕B ,  A→B , A∧B,  A∨B ,  A↔B are propositions.

Write a DrRacket procedure that will randomly generate  a proposition with a given number of operations .

**I could not complete the function. Can you help me please?**

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a homework question, I'll show you the techinque using a different example. The following grammar has two non-terminals S and T. For each non-terminal I have defined a function that generates a random string according to the rules. Since S has four rules, I pick one of the rules at random.

```
#lang racket

;;; Grammar

; The grammar has two non-terminals S and T.
; There are four rules for S and one for T.

; S -> aSa
; S -> bSb
; S -> cT
; S -> ε

; T -> dS

(define (S)
  (case (random 4) ; random number 0,1,2,3 (four rules for S)
    [(0) (string-append "a" (S) "a")]
    [(1) (string-append "b" (S) "b")]
    [(2) (string-append "c" (T))]
    [(3) ""]))

(define (T)
  ; only one rule, so no need for random here
  (string-append "d" (S)))

; generate a random string according to the grammar
(S)
```

Some example outputs:

```
"bb"
"bbcdbcdbbb"
"cdbb"
```

Comment: You have to make permutations of those lists. Each of the `P Q R...` propositions must be permuted with another of `P Q R...` putting a logic operator between them. Example `P ^ Q` `P v Q` `~P ^ Q` and so on. This could be done with [map](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=map#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29).